# Angular Material $mdPanel doesn't have a close() method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using angular material $mdPanel, i can display it using the open() method but i can't remove it (using close button like the demo). The documentation is not clear about that, the close method doesn't work. Is there any solution for that ?

[$mdPanel documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.2/demo/panel)

Comment: Any feedback or suggestions GHA?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `$mdPanel.open()`, it returns a promise. The call to the promise contains a reference to the created panel. You can call `close()` on that.

```
$res = $mdPanel.open(...);
$res.then(function(ref) {
    $scope.ref = ref;
})
```

Later on, to close, call:

```
$scope.ref.close();
```

Comment: I'm not clear on where $scope is coming from. How are you able to reference the mdPanel's scope in the then portion of the promise?

Comment: You have to inject $scope or $rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `close()` method on `$mdPanel` it is instead a method on the panel reference, which is passed on the first argument to the controller for that panel. So to be able to close the panel you need to pass a controller function in your panel definition similar to below.

Hope this helps!

```
var config = {
    ...,
    controller: PanelController,
    controllerAs: 'panelCtrl',
    template: '<div><div>Some content</div><button ng-click="panelCtrl.close()">Close</button></div>',
    ...
};

function PanelController(panelRef) {
    this.close = function () {
        panelRef && panelRef.close();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the `mdPanelRef` inside a controller and then call `mdPanelRef.close()`

```
var config = {
    ...,
    controller: PanelController

};

function PanelController(mdPanelRef) {
    this.close = function () {
        mdPanelRef.close();
    };
}
```